# Angular App Shows Nginx Default Page Instead of App Content When Running in Docker

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, docker

I'm working on a project that includes a Spring Boot backend and an Angular frontend, both containerized using Docker. The issue arises when I start the application with `docker-compose up`. Although everything seems to run correctly, when I access http://localhost:80, I'm faced with the default Nginx page instead of my Angular application's content.

Here are the details of my Docker setup:

- Backend Dockerfile

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:21-oracle as build

# Set the current working directory inside the image
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the pom.xml file
COPY mvnw .
COPY .mvn .mvn
COPY pom.xml .

# Fetch all dependencies
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline -B

# Copy the project source
COPY src src

# Package the application
RUN ./mvnw package -DskipTests

# Run the application
FROM openjdk:21-oracle
COPY --from=build /app/target/*.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

- Frontend Dockerfile:

```
# build from source
# ----------------------------
FROM node:20 AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# ----------------------------
# run with nginx
# ----------------------------
FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY --from=build /app/dist/frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
```

- nginx.conf inside frontend directory:

```
server {
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

- docker-compose.yml in root directory of project:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/myapp
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: myappuser
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: myapppass
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: update
    depends_on:
      - db

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "4200:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend

  db:
    image: postgres:16
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: myapp
      POSTGRES_USER: myappuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myapppass
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

I expected that navigating to http://localhost:80 would display the Angular application, but instead, I'm only able to see the default Nginx page. I've verified that the Angular build is successful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to lay in two things:

First of all the wrong `frontend` port mapping within your `docker-compose.yml` file. With the current configuration your frontend app is available within the `4200` port. If you want to expose it using `80` port, then you should configure the ports the following way:

```yaml
frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

Please be aware that port `80` may be used by some other application on your local machine too. Consider choosing the port that you don't plan to use with any other app.

Second problem is related to the recent Angular 17 changes as it comes to SSR and the building process. In the previous Angular versions the app was packed to the `dist/app` directory but now the `dist/app/browser` directory is being used. That's way you have to change the following line in the `frontend` Dockerfile configuration:

```
COPY --from=build /app/dist/frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
```

To:

```
COPY --from=build /app/dist/frontend/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
```

In order to make it work. Previously the directory was successfully copied but it didn't contain the `index.html` so the `nginx` has been using it's default index that hasn't been replaced.

Comment: I've changed ports to "80:80", but still get nginx default page when open localhost:80. I even tried to change ports to "4200:4200" which is angular default port, but then I get "This page isn’t working", and on port 80 I also get some error page, which is not related to angular or ngnix.

Comment: Try to provide the value "8005:80" and after building the container open `http://localhost:8005` in your browser. Do you see the frontend app there?

Comment: No, now I see "Welcome to nginx!" page on port "8005".

I've logged in to the container's terminal and checked what's inside /usr/share/nginx/html and there is actually just index.html file with "Welcome to nginx!" content. So I guess my angular app just didn't copy like specified in Dockerfile? Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely it. Check if the Angular app is even built in the `dist` folder.

Comment: Hmm, I don't even see a directory named `app` inside my container...

Comment: @LuksusHD I think I reproduced your issue and found the solution. Please see my edited post. If it answers your question please mark my answer as accepted.